# MVC AJAX Update for particular section of page not applying master page CSS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Am working on MVC With jquery and am using JQUERY to load the section of the page.

I have a div

```
   <div id="test" class="col_6 newSection">
<div>
```

And on click of the DIV am having a AJAX function and call the controller  which return the action result from the partial view

```
$(document).on("click", ".newSection", function () {
..
..
.
.
.
success: function (resp) {
$("#test").html(resp);
}
})
```

But the problem is i have the **CSS files referred in my Master Page which is not applied after the ajax call for this particular section**.

Am sure there will be a workaround which am missing. Any suggestions would be much valuable at this point.

## Update

For eaxmple. in my master page i have referred

```
<link href="~/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But whatever the classes applied there is not reflecting in my AJAX section HTML
Thanks

Comment: Hi If i am not wrong then you want to add `col_6` this class in your `test` div right?

Comment: No. I have few files referred in the header of the master page which is not applied on this ajax. I ll update my question

Comment: It seems something wrong with css class because returned partial view page should have css applied. hardcode your returned html in the parent page and see whether it has css applied.

Comment: @user2067567 I think your page is not find stylesheet `test.css` path problem in your project. Try explicitly adding classes like this `$("#test").css("class","col_6");`  and see it's working or not.